# Saddlepoint and Maximum principle relation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Theorem (The Maximum Principle)
İf f(z) is analytic and non constant in a region Ω, then its absolute value |f(z)| has no maximum in Ω.

I am working saddle point approximation.

I want to learn what is the relationship with Maximum Principle and Saddle point? How we can say from Cauchy-Riemann equations,that point can not be a maximum or minimum but must be saddle point on the surface S.(From picture)
Thank you

[image][image]

Comment: I recommend you "Infinitesimal Calculus" by Jean Dieudonné, an english translation of "Calcul infinitesimal" (in french) http://www.amazon.com/Infinitesimal-calculus-Jean-Alexandre-Dieudonne/dp/0395120349

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.Can you explain the relationship between saddle point and maximum principle ? @jeanMarie

Comment: I fear it would be a little long... Maybe, I can find on the web an accessible good reference.

Comment: Thank you, if you find, please can you share with me @JeanMarie

Comment: Here is a very nicely illustrated document: http://ac.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/lectures13/AC08-Saddle.pdf Look at the three first chapters It is aimed at people doing analytic combinatorics ; this why you will find the notation of combinatoricians [z^n]F(z) which means "the coefficient of $z^n$ in the Taylor or Laurent series F(z)". Tell me if all is OK.